# How do I correct an IF function when used with CAST function in Bigquery

Tags: if-statement, casting

SELECT
stn,
date,

-- Use the IF function to replace 999.9 values, which the dataset description explains is the default value when wind speed is missing, with NULLs instead.
IF(
wdsp="999.9",
NULL,
CAST(wdsp AS Float64)) AS wind_speed,

I kept getting error and my query cannot run

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: IF is not standard SQL. Some engines accept IIF. Standard statement however is CASE ... WHEN... ELSE... END.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Table if it is already named the column as you want to name it.
SQL can not find wdsp in your table as it might be already changed in another query.